# A Compelling Abstract Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X,Y$ imfinite sets that are not empty and $X \cap Y=\emptyset$
$P(X \cup Y)\approx P(X) \times P(Y)$

Answer (score 1):

For any disjoint pair of sets $X,Y$ we have this: a bijection is $A \in P(X \cup Y) \to (A \cap X, A \cap Y)\in P(X) \times P(Y)$.

This is the cardinal number analogue of $2^{a+b}= 2^a \cdot 2^b$.